# Why can I name a function for Binding Adapters freely?

Tags: android-studio, android-jetpack

I'm learning ['Using Binding Adapters to create custom attributes'](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-databinding/#7)

*Code A* + *Code B* works well.

If I replace the function name `hideIfZero` with `hideIfZeroNewName` just like Code C, I find *Code C*+ *Code B* works well too, why?

**Code A**

```
@BindingAdapter("app:hideIfZero")
fun hideIfZero(view: View, number: Int) {
    view.visibility = if (number == 0) View.GONE else View.VISIBLE
}
```

**Code B**

```
<ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"           
            app:hideIfZero="@{viewmodel.likes}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/like_button"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/like_button"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/like_button"
            app:progressScaled="@{viewmodel.likes}"
            tools:progressBackgroundTint="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
```

**Code C**

```
@BindingAdapter("app:hideIfZero")
fun hideIfZeroNewName(view: View, number: Int) {
    view.visibility = if (number == 0) View.GONE else View.VISIBLE
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because binding doesn't care about function name, see in the tutorial examples, setText , and setBackground , are not matching the binding name.

Answer (score 1):

> Why can I name a function for Binding Adapters freely?

Because the function name is irrelevant. Data binding works by auto-generating code based on the annotations you use on your methods and the databinding "code" you use in XML.

So, say you annotate a method that takes a `View` and set an attribute in XML:

```
@BindingAdapter("app:hideIfZero")
fun hideIfZero(view: View, number: Int) {
    view.visibility = if (number == 0) View.GONE else View.VISIBLE
}

...

app:hideIfZero="@{viewmodel.likes}"
```

The data binding annotation processor reads this *when you compile your code* and generates binding code that looks something like this (you can search Android Studio for your binding class to see exactly what it looks like, but the idea should hold):

```
class MyBinding {
    // Public setter for the view model variable in the XML
    public void setViewModel(viewModel: MyVieModel) {
        // Here will be a series of calls to set the values on views based on
        // the XML declarations and BindingAdapter annotations.

        // Here "hideIfZero" annotation is set on "hideIfZero" method, so code
        // to call that method with the view and value set in XML is generated
        hideIfZero(this.progressBar, viewModel.likes)
    }
}
```

If you change the name of the method, *when you compile your code* the processor will regenerate the code to match the new method that the annotation is set on:

```
@BindingAdapter("app:hideIfZero")
fun hideIfZeroNewName(view: View, number: Int) {
    view.visibility = if (number == 0) View.GONE else View.VISIBLE
}

class MyBinding {
    // Public setter for the view model variable in the XML
    public void setViewModel(viewModel: MyVieModel) {
        // Here will be a series of calls to set the values on views based on
        // the XML declarations and BindingAdapter annotations.

        // Here "hideIfZero" annotation is set on "hideIfZeroNewName" method,
        // so code to call that method with the view and value set in XML
        // is generated   
        hideIfZeroNewName(this.progressBar, viewModel.likes)
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!